# Как получить координаты курсора секунду назад?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Это нужно для того, чтобы при смещении курсора влево запускалась одна анимация, при смещении курсора вправо - другая, если координаты остались неизменны, то отсутствие анимации.

Пробовал через `setInterval`, но объявленная в нем переменная - локальная, и другие функции ее не видят, поэтому у меня не получается данным образом отследить передвижение курсора.

Comment: ну так сохраняйте не в локальную переменную

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример, пожалуйста. Смысл понимаю, но реализацию не понимаю :(

Answer (score 0):

Помогло следующее решение:

```
var prev_x; // задал внешнюю переменную 

function coord(){ создал функцию, которую вызываю в функции game
    setInterval(function(){ // вызываю каждый 100 мс
        prev_x = shipXY.x; // и придаю полученное значение в глобальную переменную
    },1000);
}

if ( prev_x > shipXY.x ) {
    // ваше действие
}

else if ( prev_x < shipXY.x ) {
    // ваше действие
}

else {
    // ваше действие
}
// код ниже для понимания того, как это вызывать
function game() {
    coord();
    requestAnimationFrame(game);
}

backgroundShip.onload = function() { 
    game();
}
```

Comment: Что-то у вас здесь очень не правильно. Вы внутри `requestAnimationFrame` запускаете `setInterval`. У вас с таким кодом будут миллионы раз `setInterval` вызываться.

Comment: Все верно, кажется, так оно и работает. Это вопрос скорее к тому, что систему сильно будет нагружать подобное решение? Может быть у вас есть предположение, как сделать корректнее? :)

Comment: Надо оставить что-то одно из двух. Или `requestAnimationFrame` или `setInterval`.